# Google glass OAuth invalid client

Tags: java, maven, oauth, google-glass

I am attempting to set up the Google Glass Java Mirror API Quickstart project using mvn jetty:run command. I followed the instructions given in the Google Developer Site and the instructions in the video given here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0WxkIEPJeQ. I followed both to the letter (or as close as I could) and no matter what I do I consistently receive the following error from localhost:8080:

```
Error: invalid_client
The OAuth client was not found.
Request Details
cookie_policy_enforce=false
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.timeline https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.location https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback
approval_prompt=force
client_id=375625213438.apps.googleusercontent.com 
client_secret=dhMaV4y5Mo7Ay5LGZ_utIBH_
```

I have no idea what is causing this; I don't have much experience at all with OAuth2 things at all so any help would be greatly welcome.

Comment: I tried your client ID, and get Error: disabled_client. The OAuth client was disabled.
And when I tried with my client, it worked. So there's something wrong with your client.
Check the project settings in Developer Console or register another one and try it again.